# Spring Boot + Hibernate - How to maintain @Transient fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a POJO class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "interruttori", catalog = "SMARTPARK")
public class Interruttore implements java.io.Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idInterruttore;
    private int numeroInterruttore;
    private String nomeInterruttore;
    private String descrizione;
    private List<Luce> luci;
    private String pinName;
    private boolean remoto;
    private boolean stato;
    private Date dateTime;
    private Set<Integer> activeSensors = new HashSet<Integer>();
//getters and setters and specifically
@Transient
    public Set<Integer> getActiveSensors() {
        return activeSensors;
    }

    public void setActiveSensors(Set<Integer> activeSensors) {
        this.activeSensors = activeSensors;
    }
```

It's @Transient because I don't want to persist the Set, i need it just as a "counter" in a Controller.

The controller part we need is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/sensoristica")
    public ResponseEntity<Sensoristica> findIlluminazione(@RequestParam(value="idLuce") int idLuce,
                                                        @RequestParam(value="lit") boolean lit,
                                                        @RequestParam(value="suServer") boolean suServer) {


        Sensoristica sensoristica = new Sensoristica();
        Luce luce = luceService.findById(idLuce);
        String nomeLuce = luce.getNomeLuce();
        int numeroLuce = luce.getNumeroLuce();
        sensoristica.setLuce(luce);
        sensoristica.setLit(lit);
        sensoristicaService.saveSensoristica(sensoristica);
        logger.debug("Aggiornato sensore " + numeroLuce + " ("+nomeLuce+") acceso: "+lit);
        //aggiorniamo lo stato del sensore

        luce.setLit(lit);
        luceService.updateLuce(luce);

        //qui gestisco l'interruttore
        if(suServer){

        int idInterruttore = luce.getInterruttore().getIdInterruttore();
        Interruttore interruttore = interruttoreService.findById(idInterruttore);
        Set<Integer> activeSensors = interruttore.getActiveSensors();
        logger.debug("Active sensor è " +activeSensors);
        if(lit){
        activeSensors.add(idLuce);

        logger.debug("Aggiungo id "+idLuce);
        logger.debug("Active è lungo: "+activeSensors.size());
        } else { 
            if (activeSensors.contains(idLuce)){
                activeSensors.remove(idLuce);
                logger.debug("Rimuovo id "+idLuce);
                logger.debug("Active è lungo: "+activeSensors.size());
            }
        }
        interruttore.setActiveSensors(activeSensors);
        interruttoreService.updateInterruttore(interruttore);
        boolean canShutDown = activeSensors.isEmpty();
        logger.debug("canShutDown is "+canShutDown);
```

Basically, I want to add or remove `idLuce`to the Set and then check if `activeSensors.isEmpty()`.
The problem is that every call to the Controller gives me back an empty Set, not a Set with the previous `idLuce`s inside.
How can I obtain it?

Comment: Have you got caching enabled?

Comment: no i don't have it enabled

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but if the @Transient property only maintains a value temporarily since it is not persisted, it must be stored somewhere in order for you to get the result you want, so that the second call continues to be able to access it and change it. In your case, so that `Interruttore` gets refreshed from the database and keep the cached values. Try using cache and see what happens...

Comment: Transient objects are not saved in a second level cache unfortunatly... I think i have to change approach thanks

Comment: One thing that I know will really help you is if you use [Spring Caching](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/). However this is a bit of a not so good solution because it's caching method calls, although practically you can do exactly what you want with it. Another solution you may consider is if you use Injection for services and make them store the variabes you need to cache.

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha i think i will use Injection with a map to store my variables, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually @Transient should be applied according to AccessType.

Please try setting @Transient to the field.

```
@Transient
private Set<Integer> activeSensors = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

Comment: If i put it to the field i'm getting `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: interruttori, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(active_sensors)]`

Comment: Try using  @Cacheable annotation as well which is quite simpler.  Please see documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html